# String encoding with urllib.urlencode

Tags: python, urllib

For the body of a post request I'm trying to turn:

```
    data = [
        ('p1', 'true'),
        ('table', 'f3'),
        ('ids', '/'R000000020/'')
    ]
```

into

```
p1=true&table=f3&ids='R000000020'
```

using

```
import urllib
payload = urllib.urlencode(data)
```

but I'm getting

```
'p1=true&table=f3&ids=%27R000000020%27'
```

How can I get this working correctly?

edit: I ended up using:

```
    data = [
        ('p1', 'true'),
        ('table', 'f3'),
        ('ids', "'"+'R000000020'+"'")
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Urlencode will encode `'` to `%27` . If you don't want this you can join the `data` manually :

```
payload = '&'.join(['='.join(d) for d in data])
```

Or you can replace `%27` with `'` :

```
payload = urllib.urlencode(data).replace("%27", "'")
```

Comment: I did use that as a temporary fix

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds dumb, but have you changed your data `ids` to:

```
('ids', 'R000000020')
```

Comment: @user61629, sorry I missed the quotations. you can just append the parameters which you don't want encoded. Not sure why you're doing this.

payload = urllib.urlencode([('p1', 'true'),('table', 'f3')]) + "ids='R000000020'"